# How to deal with android Collection errors?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter, nosuchelementexception

While developing Android, I wrote `Adapter` code for `RecyclerView`. But intermittently, the app closes abnormally. As a result of checking through `Crashlytics` of `Firebase`, the error contents were as follows.

[image]

It's an intermittent bug, so I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the kotlin extension function `first`, the crash report is quite clear about what's gone wrong "Collection contains no element matching the predicate". This means that the condition you check for in `first.{check on of the items in the list meets this condition}` is returning no values.

How you handle this error is up to you. I would personally replace `first` with  [firstOrNull](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first-or-null.html) and do something appropriate if null is encountered